# Socket python + send back message to client

Tags: python, sockets

I have a basic python socket, like:

server.py

```
import socket
ip   = '192.168.2.231'
port =  2005
addr = (ip, port)
serv_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv_socket.bind(addr)
serv_socket.listen(2)

con, cliente = serv_socket.accept()

receive = con.recv(1024)
if receive == '0123456789':
    #print "Accepted ACK"
    HERE - how can i send a message to client.py back

serv_socket.close()
```

How can i respond to the client.py that the sent ACK is correct?
On line 16(server.py) I perform an IF and print a message, I want send a message back to the client.py saying that the ACK is invalid / invalid

Answer (score 1):

You'll just use the client socket to send a response.

```
con, cliente = serv_socket.accept()

receive = con.recv(1024)
if receive == '0123456789':
    con.send("ACK")

serv_socket.close()
```